# $\Gamma(1)\backslash \Bbb H$ quotient meaning

Tags: number-theory, notation, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $\Bbb H$ be the upper-half complex plane and $\Gamma(1)=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (acting on $\Bbb H$ by Möbius tranformations) . My modular forms notes frequently refer to the quotient $\Gamma(1) \backslash \Bbb H$, but I'm not quite sure what this quotient means, since the upper-half plane is not a subgroup (at least on first glance). Is it maybe related to orbits, or to a fundamental set? Also, what's the meaning of the backslash? Is it some notation that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Did you ever take an algebraic topology class?

Comment: Given an action $\cdot\colon G\times X\rightarrow X$ of a group $G$ on a set $X$ (here $\Gamma(1)=\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb H$), you define $G\cdot x=\{g\cdot x|g\in G\}$ as the orbit of an element $x\in X$ and $X/G$ for the set of orbits. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers
In your case, $\mathbb H$ is a Riemann Surface and $\mathbb H/\Gamma(1)$ is as well.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Unfortunately not, but I know basic homology and cohomology if they are relevant

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz I see, but my notes read $\Gamma(1) \backslash \mathbb{H}$ instead of $\mathbb{H} \backslash \Gamma(1)$ (which by the notation you mentioned should mean the orbits of $\Gamma(1)$ on $\mathbb{H}$, are they meant to be the same?

Comment: Yes. That is a less frequently used notation, but means the same.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz I don't think so. In modular-form theory it's important to distinguish between right and left actions. So $G \backslash X$ means "quotient of X by a left G-action", while $X / G$ means "quotient of X by a right G-action", while $X \backslash G$ or $G / X$ don't mean anything at all unless X is also a group.

Comment: (The reason the left-right distinction is important is because it allows you to work with double-coset spaces $\Gamma_1 \backslash X / \Gamma_2$.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Oh, I wasn't aware, that you needed to distinguish between left and right action here (which is prominent for example in module theory), but I have indeed already seen double-coset spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a group action of $\Gamma(1)$ on $\mathbb{H}$ given by $\begin{bmatrix} 
a& b \\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}z=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. To answer your question on the slash, this is a left group action, so when we write $\Gamma(1)\backslash\mathbb{H}$ we are taking equivalence classes of $\mathbb{H}$ modulo the action of $\Gamma(1)$. For example, we have that
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
is a matrix and given any $z\in\mathbb{H}$, we have that $Tz=z+1$, so we will have that $z\sim z+1$ (and in general $z\sim z+n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, so we identify these two points under the group action. And when you mention a fundamental set, if you are talking about a fundamental domain that is precisely what is meant by $\Gamma(1)\backslash \mathbb{H}$, so it is a set such that every element of $\mathbb{H}$ is equivalent to some element of $\Gamma(1)\backslash\mathbb{H}$, and if two elements in $\Gamma(1)\backslash\mathbb{H}$ are equivalent then they must lie on the boundary. It is a well-known theorem that you can look up (say in Serre's A Course in Arithmetic or other books) that you can this has a fundamental domain of
$$\Gamma(1)\backslash\mathbb{H}=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{H}:\vert x\vert\leq \frac{1}{2},\vert x+iy\vert\geq 1\}$$
Thus, that is what is meant by $\Gamma(1)\backslash\mathbb{H}$, and then you can actually view this as a hyperbolic manifold (since $\mathbb{H}$ can by viewed as a hyperbolic space, and this is the quotient of hyperbolic space by a Lie group). This is sometimes referred to as the modular surface if you want to look more into it.

Answer (score 5):

This refers to the set of orbits of points in $\mathcal{H}$ under the action of the modular group $\Gamma(1)$.

The image to have in mind is the fundamental domain, which is the shaded part in the following image (taken from wikipedia)

[image: Fundamental domain]

More specifically, the set of orbits can be represented by the points in the interior of the shaded part and a choice of "one half" of the points on the boundary.

The set of orbits can be thought of as a Riemann surface, and when compactified by adding a *cusp* at $\infty$ it becomes a compact Riemann surface. More generally, the set of orbits of the upper half-plane under any congruence sugroup, $\Gamma(N) \backslash \mathcal{H}$, can be similarly compactified by adding a finite number of cusps.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant piece of AT is the covering theory, specifically, regular coverings; there you encounter the notation $X/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a group acting continuously on a topological space $X$. The space $X/\Gamma$ is the quotient space of $X$ by the $\Gamma$-action, equipped with the quotient topology.

The remaining mystery to resolve is the backslash notation favored by people studying lattices in Lie groups. Here is the story:

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of a Lie group $G$ (e.g. $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ as in your case). Consider a maximal compact subgroup $K< G$. The **right** quotient $G/K$ is naturally diffeomorphic to a certain homogeneous space (a Riemannian manifold) $X$. In your case, $K=SO(2)$, $X$ is the hyperbolic plane. Now, you are left with the **left** action of $\Gamma$ on $G$, hence, the **left** action of $\Gamma$ on $G/K=X$. How would one denote the quotient of $X$ by this left action of $\Gamma$? A topologist would simply write $X/\Gamma$, which translates into ugly and unclear $G/K/\Gamma$. Thus, people in your field, write instead $\Gamma\backslash X$ or, frequently, $\Gamma  \backslash G/K$, where the backslash indicates the quotient by the **left** action of $\Gamma$.